# Should you forward declare a class as much as possible?

Tags: objective-c, forward-declaration

In [Effective Objective-C](http://www.effectiveobjectivec.com/), Matt Galloway suggests the following:

"Always import headers at the very deepest point possible. This usually means forward declaring classes in a header and importing their corresponding headers in an implementation. Doing so avoids coupling classes together as much as possible."

The issue with using this practice project wide is that anything that uses your class will need to import the forward declaring class as well.  This seems to be a drawback for the client just for the benefit of avoiding potentially increased compile time.  The reduction in coupling also doesn't make sense because by virtue of using forward declaration, the coupling is already established. Is this suggestion a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

> The issue with using this practice project wide is that anything that uses your class will need to import the forward declaring class as well.

I think you misunderstood Matt's advise: the idea is to forward-declare the class *together* with the class that uses it in its declaration, so that your header remains usable on its own, without requiring your clients to do anything special.

Here is a quick example: let's say you wish to use class `SingleWidget` in your class `DoubleWidget`. However, the interface that your class exposes always uses `SingleWidget` through a pointer or through a reference; only the implementation calls methods of `SingleWidget`. Matt's suggestion is to do this

DoubleWidget.h

```
// Use forward declaration in the header
class SingleWidget;

class DoubleWidget {
    SingleWidget &one;
    SingleWidget &two;
public:
    DoubleWidget(SingleWidget& a, SingleWidget& b) : one(a), two(b) {}
    void play();
};
```

DoubleWidget.cpp

```
#include "SingleWidget.h"
// Include the header when you cannot avoid including it
#include "DoubleWidget.h"

void DoubleWidget::play() {
    one.play();
    two.play();
}
```

instead of this:

DoubleWidget.h

```
// Do not include the header where a forward declaration is sufficient
#include "SingleWidget.h"

class DoubleWidget {
    SingleWidget &one;
    SingleWidget &two;
public:
    DoubleWidget(SingleWidget& a, SingleWidget& b) : one(a), two(b) {}
    void play();
};
```

DoubleWidget.cpp

```
#include "DoubleWidget.h"

void DoubleWidget::play() {
    one.play();
    two.play();
}
```

Note that in both cases it is sufficient for the users of your `DoubleWidget` class to include `DoubleWidget.h` header. However, in the second case the users also get full definition of the `SingleWidget` class without asking for it.

> The reduction in coupling also doesn't make sense because by virtue of using forward declaration, the coupling is already established.

You do get some coupling there, but it is very weak: your class knows that the other class exists, and that's about it. In contrast, when you include the header, your class knows everything about the other class: it knows its structure, its member functions, the classes that other class relies upon, and so on. It is a good idea to not "dump" all this information into the public interface of your own class.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  The reason why we need to forward declare in the header is because we are either returning an object of that type or we are using a property of that type.  In either case, it's likely the client would need to have full info about the type.  So it seems like the case of wanting to use forward declaration to minimize type exposure is rarely necessary, no?

Comment: Thanks on that note. Would you say then *only* if it's intended solely for middle man, that it should be forwarded? If not, the header should be declared? The problem I see with using forward declaration throughout the project is the chain reaction it can cause - meaning a client would potentially have to import multiple headers just to use one thing because everything, including property of property, etc. uses forward declaration.

Comment: I am trying to avoid surprises esp in the case when I am returning the an object of a type from my method.  The client won't be able to use it at all without importing it.  I still don't get the dependency factor, because by virtue of using forward declaration, dependency is already established.  It's not like we are using id.

Comment: Thanks again.  By class + all of its dependencies, do you mean dependencies of dependencies?